# Getting the error "the trait Sized is not implemented" when trying to return a value from a vector

Tags: rust

I am trying to return the values of a vector:

```rust
fn merge<'a>(left: &'a [i32], right: &'a [i32]) -> [i32] {
    let mut merged: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    // push elements to merged
    *merged
}
```

I get the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:1:52
  |
1 | fn merge<'a>(left: &'a [i32], right: &'a [i32]) -> [i32] {
  |                                                    ^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[i32]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

I can't find out how to fix this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it is impossible to return a `[T]`.

Rust has owned vectors (`Vec<T>`), slices (`&[T]`) and fixed-size arrays (`[T; N]`, where `N` is a non-negative integer like `6`).

A slice is composed of a pointer to data and a length. This is what your `left` and `right` values are. However, what *isn't* specified in a slice is who ultimately **owns the data**. Slices just borrow data from something else. You can treat the `&` as a signal that the data is borrowed.

A `Vec` is one thing that owns data and can let other things borrow it via a slice. For your problem, you need to allocate some memory to store the values, and `Vec` does that for you. You can then return the entire `Vec`, transferring ownership to the caller.

The specific error message means that the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate for the type `[i32]`, because it's never meant to be allocated directly. You'll see this error for other things in Rust, usually when you try to dereference a *trait object*, but that's distinctly different from the case here.

Here's the most likely fix you want:

```
fn merge(left: &[i32], right: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut merged = Vec::new();
    // push elements to merged
    merged
}
```

Additionally, you don't need to specify lifetimes here, and I removed the redundant type annotation on your `merged` declaration.

See also:

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [Why can fixed-size arrays be on the stack, but str cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673145/155423)
- [Why is `let ref a: Trait = Struct` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36057645/155423)