# Convert format!() from String to &'static str

Tags: string, rust

I'm stumped on how to interpolate a number and return it in the correct format. I started with the function returning `String` but then the compiler wanted `&'static str`. I've read about `to_owned` but it's not clicking in my head yet. What is the "right" way to do what I'm attempting?

```
fn ordinal_name(num: i32) -> &'static str {
    if num == 1 {
        "1st"
    } else if num == 2 {
        "2nd"
    } else if num == 3 {
        "3rd"
    } else {
        format!("{}th", num)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ordinal_name(5));
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
1 | fn ordinal_name(num: i32) -> &'static str {
  |                              ------------ expected `&'static str` because of return type
...
9 |         format!("{}th", num)
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `std::string::String`
  |
  = note: expected type `&'static str`
             found type `std::string::String`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

This is not a duplicate of `String to &'static str` - I'm trying to figure how to interpolate an integer with a string and then return a `&static str`.

Comment: I think this really needs a reference to [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), the linked duplicate is not good enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706429/return-either-a-borrowed-or-owned-type-in-rust/36707468#36707468 is a start

Comment: [Example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cae31659a0caa396c2702039b5e16964&version=stable)

Comment: *I'm trying to figure how to interpolate an integer with a string and then return a `&static str`* => "I'm trying to figure how to [create a `String`] and then return a `&static str`". This is indeed a duplicate; the path you take to create the `String` doesn't matter. `format!` creates a `String`.

Comment: As an aside, your function will not produce the correct output for numbers like `23`.

Comment: @Shepmaster, you're right. Luckily this only needs to go to 12 ;)