# Confusing error in Rust with trait object lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime, trait-objects

Can anyone tell what the problem is with the following code? The compiler is complaining about lifetimes, but the error message makes absolutely no sense. I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing seems to help.

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

trait Trait<'a> {
    fn accept(&mut self, &'a u8);
}

struct Impl<'a>{
    myref: Option<&'a u8>,
}
impl<'a> Trait<'a> for Impl<'a> {
    fn accept(&mut self, inp: &'a u8) { self.myref = Some(inp); }
}

fn new<'a>() -> Box<Trait<'a> + 'a> {
    Box::new(Impl{myref: None})
}

fn user<'a>(obj: &mut Trait<'a>) {}

fn parent<'a>(x: &'a u8) {
    let mut pool = new();
    user(pool.borrow_mut());
}
```

The compiler error is

```
error: `pool` does not live long enough
  --> src/wtf.rs:22:10
   |
22 |     user(pool.borrow_mut());
   |          ^^^^ does not live long enough
23 | }
   | - borrowed value dropped before borrower
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

Which makes absolutely no sense. How is the borrower outliving anything? I'm not even using the borrowed value!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, this *does* make sense, but it's hard to see due to lifetime elision.  So, here's your code with *all* the lifetimes written out explicitly, and with irrelevant details culled:

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

trait Trait<'a> {}

struct Impl<'a> {
    myref: Option<&'a u8>,
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for Impl<'a> {}

fn new<'a>() -> Box<Trait<'a> + 'a> {
    Box::new(Impl { myref: None })
}

fn user<'a, 'b>(obj: &'b mut (Trait<'a> + 'b)) {}

fn parent() {
/* 'i: */   let mut pool/*: Box<Trait<'x> + 'x>*/ = new();
/* 'j: */   let pool_ref/*: &'i mut Box<Trait<'x> + 'x>*/ = &mut pool;
            /* BorrowMut<T>::borrow_mut<'d>(&'d mut Self) -> &'d mut T */
/* 'k: */   let pool_borrow/*: &'i mut (Trait<'x> + 'x)*/ = Box::borrow_mut(pool_ref);
            user(pool_borrow);
}
```

Now, from the perspective of the last line of `parent`, we can work out the following equivalences by just reading the definition of `user` and substituting the lifetimes we have in `parent`:

- `'a` = `'x`
- `'b` = `'i`
- `'b` = `'x`

Furthermore, this lets us conclude that:

- `'x` = `'i`

This is the problem.  Because of the way you've defined `user`, you've put yourself in a situation where the lifetime of the `pool_ref` borrow (which is equal to the lifetime of the `pool` storage location you're borrowing from) must be the same as the lifetime `'x` being used in the thing being *stored* in `pool`.

It's a bit like the `Box` being able to have a pointer to itself before it exists, which doesn't make any sense.

Either way, the fix is simple.  Change `user` to actually have the correct type:

```
fn user<'a, 'b>(obj: &'b mut (Trait<'a> + 'a)) {}
```

This matches the type produced by `new`.  Alternately, *just don't use `borrow_mut`*:

```
user(&mut *pool)
```

*This* works because it is "re-borrowing".  Calling `borrow_mut` translates the lifetimes more or less directly, but re-borrowing allows the compiler to narrow the borrows to shorter lifetimes.  To put it another way, explicitly calling `borrow_mut` doesn't allow the compiler enough freedom to "fudge" the lifetimes to make them all line up, re-borrowing *does*.

As a quick aside:

> I'm not even using the borrowed value!

*Irrelevant.*  Rust does type- and lifetime-checking *entirely* locally.  It *never* looks at the body of another function to see what it's doing; it goes on the interface alone.  The compiler neither checks, nor cares, what you're doing *inside* a different function.

Comment: Where does the `'b = 'x` restriction come from?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copy+pasted the already fixed version of the example!  To clarify, `&'i mut (Trait<'x> + 'x)` (the argument) is unified with `&'b mut (Trait<'a> + 'b)` (the signature of `user`, before being fixed).  This means that `'b` is unified with *both* `'i` and `'x`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I suppose new probably should return something like Trait<'a> + 'b then, but the compiler complained when I didn't have the + 'a in there.

Comment: @Antimony No, I think `+ 'a` is *probably* more correct: it doesn't seem sensible for the trait object to be bound by two *different* lifetimes.  (In this case, anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that there's more to the error message:

```
error: `pool` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:10
   |>
25 |>     user(pool.borrow_mut());
   |>          ^^^^
note: reference must be valid for the block at 23:25...
  --> src/main.rs:23:26
   |>
23 |> fn parent<'a>(x: &'a u8) {
   |>                          ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 24:25
  --> src/main.rs:24:26
   |>
24 |>     let mut pool = new();
   |>                          ^
```

Let's look at `user`:

```
fn user<'a>(obj: &mut Trait<'a>) {}
```

This says that it will accept a mutable reference (with an unnamed lifetime) to a trait object parameterized with the lifetime `'a`.

Turning to `new`, I'd say the method is **highly** suspicious:

```
fn new<'a>() -> Box<Trait<'a> + 'a> {
    Box::new(Impl { myref: None })
}
```

This says that it will return a boxed trait object with *whatever lifetime the caller specifies*. [That basically never makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).

All that said, I'm not clear why the code chooses to use `borrow_mut`. I would have written that more directly:

```
user(&mut *pool);
```

This dereferences the `Box<Trait>` to get a `Trait`, then takes a mutable reference, yielding `&mut Trait`, which compiles.

I cannot currently explain why `BorrowMut` differs in behavior.

Comment: How do you pass the right lifetime to new in that case? I assumed the compiler would choose the right one automatically. If I try to pass an explicit lifetime in, it gives an error about passing too many lifetime parameters. P.S. I posted the complete error message I saw. I'm not sure why the compiler gives you a longer error message.

Comment: @Antimony you don't pass one in; it's always inferred from the code. In this case there's only a single possible lifetime - `'static` so the method should probably be `fn new() -> Box<Trait<'static> + 'static>` (which I *believe* is the same as `fn new() -> Box<Trait>`).

Comment: But that doesn't make sense because the returned object won't actually have static lifetime. Or does it just get implicitly narrowed later on?

Comment: @Antimony that's correct that the returned *value* won't have the static lifetime, but it can only *contain* static references. Try to make a smaller example that returns a reference that isn't static and you could se what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure *why* this error happens, but I can give solutions!

First, it seems that using [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.BorrowMut.html#tymethod.borrow_mut) unnecessarily restricts the lifetime of the returned reference. Using operators to create the reference solves the error.

```
fn parent() {
    let mut pool = new();
    user(&mut *pool);
}
```

However, if we *don't* do that, we can solve the error by adding a lifetime bound to the `Trait` object in `user`'s `obj` argument.

```
fn user<'a>(obj: &mut (Trait<'a> + 'a)) {}
```