# Why would a function taking no arguments and returning a reference have a lifetime error?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Update: this question has been answered in [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)

Also the confusing example that mentioned has been cleared in the [new Rust book](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html).

Based on the closure examples in the Rust book:

```
fn factory() -> &(Fn(i32) -> i32) {
    let num = 5;    
    |x| x + num
}

let f = factory();   
let answer = f(1);
assert_eq!(6, answer);
```

This example would have error:

```
error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
fn factory() -> &(Fn(i32) -> i32) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I found this `fn factory() -> &(Fn(i32) -> i32)` can be abstracted as

```
fn foo<'a>() -> &'a Someclosure.
```

I am trying to understand why a function takes no arguments would have a lifetime problem here.

Is that similar to the example given in the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision) in Rust book:`fn foo<'a>() -> &'a str`? This seems to be a valid example about how to use lifetime.

Comment: Note that the examples you are looking are just examples of **syntax**; they aren't necessarily *valid* or *useful*.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. The other related post answers everything!

Comment: You may wish to review [the new version of the book](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) which removes that confusing line.