# Is there a way to use locked standard input and output in a constructor to live as long as the struct you're constructing?

Tags: rust, stdout, stdin, lifetime

I'm building a `PromptSet` that can ask a series of questions in a row. For testing reasons, it allows you to pass a reader and writer instead of using stdin & stdout directly.

Because stdin and stdout are the common use case, I would like to create a default "constructor" that allows the user to produce a `PromptSet<StdinLock, StdoutLock>` without needing any parameters. Here's the code so far:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead, StdinLock, StdoutLock, Write};

pub struct PromptSet<R, W>
where
    R: BufRead,
    W: Write,
{
    pub reader: R,
    pub writer: W,
}

impl<R, W> PromptSet<R, W>
where
    R: BufRead,
    W: Write,
{
    pub fn new(reader: R, writer: W) -> PromptSet<R, W> {
        return PromptSet {
            reader: reader,
            writer: writer,
        };
    }

    pub fn default<'a>() -> PromptSet<StdinLock<'a>, StdoutLock<'a>> {
        let stdin = io::stdin();
        let stdout = io::stdout();

        return PromptSet {
            reader: stdin.lock(),
            writer: stdout.lock(),
        };
    }

    pub fn prompt(&mut self, question: &str) -> String {
        let mut input = String::new();

        write!(self.writer, "{}: ", question).unwrap();
        self.writer.flush().unwrap();
        self.reader.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        return input.trim().to_string();
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

`StdinLock` and `StdoutLock` both need a lifetime declared. To complicate it, I think the original `stdin()`/`stdout()` handles need to live at least as long as the locks do. I would like the references to `StdinLock` and `StdoutLock` to live as long as my `PromptSet` does but no matter what I try I can't get it to work. Here is the error that I keep getting:

```
error[E0597]: `stdin` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:21
   |
30 |             reader: stdin.lock(),
   |                     ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
33 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 25:5...
  --> src/main.rs:25:5
   |
25 | /     pub fn default<'a>() -> PromptSet<StdinLock<'a>, StdoutLock<'a>> {
26 | |         let stdin = io::stdin();
27 | |         let stdout = io::stdout();
28 | |
...  |
32 | |         };
33 | |     }
   | |_____^

error[E0597]: `stdout` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:21
   |
31 |             writer: stdout.lock(),
   |                     ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
32 |         };
33 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 25:5...
  --> src/main.rs:25:5
   |
25 | /     pub fn default<'a>() -> PromptSet<StdinLock<'a>, StdoutLock<'a>> {
26 | |         let stdin = io::stdin();
27 | |         let stdout = io::stdout();
28 | |
...  |
32 | |         };
33 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

It's perfectly possible I just don't understand the concept of lifetimes or something else super basic.

Comment: If the question is rephrased to stdin/stdout it's not a duplicate, since stdin/stdout are a rather special case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `lock` method's signature is `fn lock(&self) -> StdinLock`, which, when fully expanded with lifetime annotations, is `fn lock<'a>(&'a self) -> StdinLock<'a>`. Thus the `StdinLock` can only live as long as the value that the `lock` method is called on. Since you defined `stdin` in this very function, the `StdinLock` can't outlive the function. This is the same as [returning a reference to a local value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423). You also [can't return the reference and the referred-to value together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423).

You can't do this, and you can't work around it. The only fix is to have the `default` method take a `Stdin` and a `Stdout` object as arguments.

That said, you *can* work around it. Yes I know, I just said the exact opposite, but it's more of a "no one other than me will ever use stdin/stdout" **(a.k.a., `println!` will not work anymore!)**.

In Rust 1.26, you can use [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) to leak the `Stdin` to a `&'static Stdin`, which will yield a `StdinLock<'static>`. Before Rust 1.26, you can use the [`leak`](https://crates.io/crates/leak/) crate:

```
pub fn default() -> PromptSet<StdinLock<'static>, StdoutLock<'static>> {
    let stdin = Box::leak(Box::new(io::stdin()));
    let stdout = Box::leak(Box::new(io::stdout()));

    PromptSet {
        reader: stdin.lock(),
        writer: stdout.lock(),
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've considered the `'static` lifetime but, wow, I didn't think that would cause problems too. I can see the usability issues in taking control of `stdin` & `stdout` for prolonged periods of time so perhaps I'll let this be. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to implement `default` that returns `PrompSet<HelperIn, HelperOut>`, with `HelperIn` and `HelperOut` being classes that contain (own) instances of `Stdin` and `Stdout`, and implement `BufRead` and `Write` respectively (by locking the stream for each operation and calling the appropriate method on the lock guard)? It seems like it should be possible, but when I wrote it up, it wouldn't compile due to `BufRead::fill_buf` not satisfying the life-time requirements.

Comment: That would create a broken `BufRead` implementation. You would loose all buffered bytes that weren't read within the `BufRead` call. What you can do is to implement the buffering yourself, but then you would be mixing arbitrary bytes between different readers. There's a reason `StdinLock` doesn't already work like this.

Comment: This is extremely useful in case when you e.g. need to lock stdin and pass it to code that (for various technical reasons) expects `impl Read + 'static` with the intent of exhausting it. Since stdin is about to be exhausted and it's a short-lived process, it is not an issue that it will not be usable afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Might be not really the answer to your question, but to a similar problem. Here's my solution.

The main trick here is to call `stdin.lock()` for every single line.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::Stdin;

struct StdinWrapper {
    stdin: Stdin,
}

impl Iterator for StdinWrapper {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let stdin = &self.stdin;
        let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();
        match lines.next() {
            Some(result) => Some(result.expect("Cannot read line")),
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Callers of this method should not know concrete source of the strings.
 * It could be Stdin, a file, DB, or even aliens from SETI.
 */
fn read() -> Box<Iterator<Item = String>> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    Box::new(StdinWrapper { stdin })
}

fn main() {
    let lines = read();

    for line in lines {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```