# How to use the Rust type system to prevent output to stdout?

Tags: rust, locking, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm working on a data pipeline node, an application that takes a continuous supply of data from `stdin`, processes it, and outputs the result continuously to `stdout` in a streaming fashion.

Considering the data interchange format is pre-determined, I need a handy way of barring my debug output from feeding to stdout simultaneously. Essentially, a global lock. True, I could just get rid of all the debug statements, but it's more of an academic exercise.

**So let's make a function which can write to `stdout`, and locks `stdout` as long as it remains in scope so the type system itself prevents other places in the code from writing to `stdout`**:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub fn make_push_output<'a>() -> &'a impl Fn(String) -> io::Result<()> {
    let handle = io::stdout().lock();

    &|output: String| {
        handle.write(output.to_string().as_bytes())?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Cool, a global lock on `stdout` that stays in place until the output `push_output()` function goes out of scope, but it doesn't work. I get a whole list of borrow checker errors:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     let handle = io::stdout().lock();
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value only lives until here
  |                  |
  |                  temporary value does not live long enough
  |
  = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:6:6
   |
6  |       &|output: String| {
   |  ______^
7  | |         handle.write(output.to_string().as_bytes())?;
8  | |
9  | |         Ok(())
10 | |     }
   | |_____^ temporary value does not live long enough
11 |   }
   |   - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 3:25...
  --> src/lib.rs:3:25
   |
3  | pub fn make_push_output<'a>() -> &'a impl Fn(String) -> io::Result<()> {
   |                         ^^

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `handle`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/lib.rs:6:6
  |
6 |     &|output: String| {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `handle`
7 |         handle.write(output.to_string().as_bytes())?;
  |         ------ `handle` is borrowed here
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `handle` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
6 |     &move |output: String| {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0387]: cannot borrow data mutably in a captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         handle.write(output.to_string().as_bytes())?;
  |         ^^^^^^
  |
help: consider changing this closure to take self by mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:6:6
  |
6 |       &|output: String| {
  |  ______^
7 | |         handle.write(output.to_string().as_bytes())?;
8 | |
9 | |         Ok(())
10| |     }
  | |_____^
```

I've been trying for well over an hour to fix this sequence of borrow checker errors on these 7 lines of code. Here's a non-exhaustive list of steps I've taken so far that haven't worked:

- Change the lifetime of `make_push_output`
- Add explicit type and lifetime annotation to `handle`
- Declare a variable for `io::stdout()` and annotate with type and lifetime
- Add explicit type and lifetime annotation to the closure
- Declare a local function instead of using a closure, couldn't capture the environment
- Use `move` semantics on the closure, not the brightest move, but I was grasping at straws

Comment: Regardless of the error you get, locking a handle to stdout doesn't actually buy you anything – it only locks this specific handle.  You can easily create and use a different handle, even while the handle you hold is locked.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. The standard output lock is [*reentrant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex):

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let out = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = out.lock();
    writeln!(handle, "handle: {}", 1);

    println!("Debugging output");

    writeln!(handle, "handle: {}", 2);
    drop(handle)
}
```

This prints:

```
handle: 1
Debugging output
handle: 2
```

No amount of type juggling can prevent the same thread from re-acquiring a lock to standard out / error and printing in the middle of your output.

---

Your compiler errors are addressed by:

- Returning an `& impl ...`

  - [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- Trying to return `stdout` and its lock together

  - [Is there a way to use locked standard input and output in a constructor to live as long as the struct you're constructing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41549516/155423)
  - [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: So a theoretical option would be to lock stdout in a _different_ thread, and push all desired output to a queue which is then printed to stdout by the thread that holds the lock.  However, this would lead to a deadlock as soon as the main thread tries to use `println!()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach and it still wouldn't technically meet OPs requirement to use *the type system* to solve the problem, as AFAICT Rust's type system is simply not powerful enough to provide that restriction.