# Why is a lifetime unused on a struct that I have a reference to?

Tags: rust

The following won't compile:

```
struct Person<'z> {
    street_address: String,
    postcode: String,
    city: String,

    company_name: String,
    position: String,
    annual_income: usize,
}

struct PersonBuilder<'z> {
    person: &'z Person<'z>,
}

impl<'z> PersonBuilder<'z> {
    fn new() -> PersonBuilder<'z> {
        PersonBuilder {
            person: Person {
                street_address: "".to_string(),
                postcode: "".to_string(),
                city: "".to_string(),
                company_name: "".to_string(),
                position: "".to_string(),
                annual_income: 0,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'z` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:1:15
  |
1 | struct Person<'z> {
  |               ^^ unused type parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `'z` or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

But that's not true, is it? I mean, `PersonBuilder` keeps a reference to a person as `Person<'z>` and when I instantiate it with `PersonBuilder::new()`, clearly the type parameter is in play to tie the two lifetimes together. So what's going on here?

Comment: I don't see any actual use of `'z` lifetime for `Person`; nothing weird here.

Comment: Why don't you use `String::new()` instead of `"".to_string()`?

Comment: Also, you should use `to_owned` instead of `to_string` to convert &str to String.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner that's outdated information. There's no performance difference between the two, and arguably `to_string` is more obvious what it does.

Comment: @Shepmaster [Wow, you're right!](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32586) Thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is completely correct here; `'z` is not used on `Person`. Remove it from `Person` and from `PersonBuilder`:

```
struct Person { /* ... */ }

struct PersonBuilder<'z> {
    person: &'z Person,
}
```

One you remove that, **what you are trying to do is impossible**. See [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423). Remove all lifetimes and references from your code and it will work.

---

> `PersonBuilder` keeps a reference to a person

Yes, that's what `&Person` would be.

> as `Person<'z>`

`Person<'z>` indicates that the `Person` struct *contains* a reference of the specified lifetime. `&'z Person` is a reference to a person with the specified lifetime.

> instantiate it with `PersonBuilder::new()`, clearly the type parameter

Which "type parameter" are you referring to, as I don't see any in this code. While it's true that lifetimes and type parameters are both *kinds* of generics, they are different kinds of generics and are not treated the same.

---

You may also be interested in the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Person { /* ... */ }

impl PersonBuilder {
    fn new() -> PersonBuilder {
        PersonBuilder {
            person: Person::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried removing the lifetime, but then other parts break. Self-contained example here: https://gist.github.com/nesteruk/8b6e967affbd27e6c099f20be18d157a

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk please go back and re-read my answer. My **third** and **fourth** sentences explain that error: *One you remove that, what you are trying to do is impossible. See [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).* Then my **fifth** sentence explains how to fix it: *Remove all lifetimes and references from your code and it will work.*

Comment: that, by itself, did not help: https://gist.github.com/nesteruk/d1fcfbd8d9fbedce27a478a26a8d65cf