# Is a returned value moved or not?

Tags: rust

With this code:

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

struct Rectangle {
    p1: Point,
    p2: Point,
}

impl Rectangle {
    pub fn new(x1: f64, y1: f64, x2: f64, y2: f64) -> Rectangle {
        let r = Rectangle {
            p1: Point { x: x1, y: y1 },
            p2: Point { x: x2, y: y2 },
        };
        // some code where r is used
        r
    }
}

let rectangle = Rectangle::new(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0);
```

From a memory point of view, is `rectangle` the same instance as `r`, or is it a copy of `r`?

Do I have to explicitly return by reference (something like `&r`)?

I have to create millions of rectangles, and I don't want there to be useless copies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> From a memory point of view, is `rectangle` the same instance as `r`, or is it a copy of `r`?

**Unspecified**.

The Rust language specifies the **semantics** of the language, and while they do constrain the implementation somewhat, in this case they do not. How a return value is passed up the call stack is part of the **ABI**, and not only is the ABI unstable (in Rust), it's also platform specific.

> Do I have to explicitly return by reference (something like `&r`)?

[Returning by reference is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).

You could return a `Box<Rectangle>` but the cost of the memory allocation would dwarf the cost of copying a `Rectangle` in the first place, so it's hardly advisable.

You could force this using *output parameters* instead, but this has other issues:

- if you have a `&mut Rectangle` parameter, you first need to have a valid instance, which has to be initialized; rather wasteful,
- if you have a `*mut Rectangle` pointing to uninitialized memory, you need to use `unsafe` code, hardly satisfying.

However...

> I have to create millions of rectangles, and I don't want there to be useless copies.

**I think you are worrying for nothing.**

The first rule of performance tuning is **measure first**; and I doubt that you'll be able to observe a performance issue in the *creation* of those millions of rectangles.

The compiler has multiple tricks up its sleeves, such as:

- not even materializing the `rectangle` instance to start with, but pass its components via CPU registers instead,
- inlining `new` at the call site, avoiding any copy whatsoever,
- ...

Thus, before worrying about the cost of copying 4 `f64`, I would implement the naive solution, compile in release mode, and observe what happens.

Comment: Does Rust gurantee calling `drop()` to free up resources of an original value when copying  has "de facto" taken place?

Comment: @Mergasov: I think your mental model is off. There are two operations in Rust, identified by two traits: `Clone` and `Copy`. When you create a `clone`, you (the user) specify the logic involved in creating the clone; as an example, for a `String` it means allocating a second buffer and copying the contents of the first there. After cloning, both instances live their lives independently from one another. If you don't need to type `.clone()`, Rust just _moved_ the instance. If an instance is moved, it is not dropped. If an instance is copied (`Copy`), dropping is a no-op.

Comment: @Mergasov: And therefore, the _reverse_ is guaranteed. Rust guarantees that when it _bit copies_ a value (whether moving or `Copy`ing) it will never call `Drop`.