# How do I set the return value's lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following method to check if an `String` ID exists. If it doesn't, generate and then return it:

```
fn generate_id(&self) -> ID<'m> {
    let id = nanoid::generate(15);
    while self[&id].is_some() {
        id = nanoid::generate(15);
    };
    id
}
```

`ID` is a type alias: `type ID<'id> = &'id String;`

The return value needs to be `&'m std::string::String` but `id` is `std::string::String`.

I have tried doing:

```
let id: ID<'m> = nanoid::generate(15);
```

but then it gives the same error that the method is giving only for `id`.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. We don't know what the signature of `nanoid::generate` is for sure, or what the implementation of `self[]` is for the code presented.

Answer (score 2):

Lifetimes are descriptive, not prescriptive. You don't set lifetimes; they are a consequence of the program you write.

You are trying to return a reference to a local variable. That is not valid, and there is no lifetime you can write to make it valid.

You have an X/Y problem. The real question is why you feel the need to return a reference.

Comment: I agree with your points, but (presumably) OP solved their case because they answered, even though you and I agree it's impossible based on the information given. The question feels like it's unanswerable (or a dupe of something).

Comment: I'd also have a minor quibble with the terminology "temporary". Temporary would be the `String` in `String::new().trim()`; this would just be a local variable.

Comment: Good point about temporary. I still think my answer is important to other readers, simply because the OPs self-answer makes no sense.

Answer (score -3):

You need to focus on where the variable is set, not where you actually return the variable.

In this case, change `nanoid::generate(15);` to `&nanoid::generate(15);`:

```
fn generate_id(&self) -> ID<'m> {
    let id: ID<'m> = &nanoid::generate(15);
    while self[&id].is_some() {
        id = &nanoid::generate(15);
    };
    id
}
```

This ensures that the initial type of the variable has the lifetime and supplying the value as a reference ensures that the variable has the correct lifetime.

Comment: If `nanoid::generate` returns a `String`, as you say in the question, then this code cannot work because you [cannot return a reference to a value created in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).