# "Expected reference, found struct Rc" when cloning and returning an Rc

Tags: rust

I have a piece of code like this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct A(bool);

impl A {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &Rc<RefCell<bool>> {
        &Rc::new(RefCell::new(self.0))
    }

    fn copy_ref(&self) -> &Rc<RefCell<bool>> {
        Rc::clone(self.get_ref())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A(true);
    a.copy_ref();
}
```

and I received warning complaining about the `Rc::clone` function not getting a reference:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         Rc::clone(self.get_ref())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found struct `std::rc::Rc`
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<bool>>`
              found type `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<bool>>`
```

I have been working on this all night but I cannot get it to work. The method `get_ref` is already typed as returning `&Rc<RefCell<bool>>`, but why would the compiler give the error?

Answer (score 3):

**The error is not talking about the argument you put into `Arc::clone()`, but the whole expression `Rc::clone(...)`** which has a different type (`Rc<...>`) than the return type of your function (`&Rc<...>`).

If you were passing a wrong argument to `Rc::clone`, it would like look this:

```
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |         Rc::clone(false)
   |                   ^^^^^ expected reference, found bool
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::rc::Rc<_>`
              found type `bool`
```

So the naive way to fix the type error is to write `&Rc::clone(...)` instead. Then the last expression of your function has the same type as your function's declared return type. But as you will notice, you will get other errors afterwards.

Let's take a step back to see that your approach is flawed here. For the most important point, please see [**"Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function). Spoiler: you really don't want to. So constructs like your `get_ref()` just don't make sense, as you return a reference to a variable you create inside your function (a variable of type `Rc`).

In your case the direct solution is probably pretty simple: just remove the reference. `Rc<T>` is already a pointer/reference type, so there is no need (in general) to have a reference to it.

However, since you are using `Rc`, you are probably interested in reference counting. So in that case, you probably shouldn't create a new `Rc` every time the function is called. Otherwise you could end up with a bunch of `Rc`s with reference count 1, which is not really the point. So instead, your type `A` should already store an `Rc<RefCell<bool>>`.

But all I'm doing here is guessing what you actually want to do which is not clear from your question. Maybe you can ask a different question, or add the information to this question, or explain this in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I know that my code example is not a good one in terms of good rust practices. But just ignore that for now. The point I want to ask is that "why `Rc::clone` doesn't accept my argument in terms of type?"

Comment: @Chromium I did address that: you just misunderstood the compiler error. `Rc::clone` *does* accept your argument. Try to write `Rc::clone(self.get_ref()); unimplemented!()` as the body of `copy_ref`. Then you'll see. Also: it is not about good practices. In Rust, the compiler will refuse to compile your code (even if you fix your type error), and in languages like C++ you would access garbage memory and trigger undefined behavior.