# It is possible to collect a &mut from an iterator?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, ownership

I am trying to learn more about ownership. Here is some code that doesn't work because `collect` doesn't let you get a `&mut String`:

```
fn search(word: &str, data: &mut Vec<String>) {
    data = data
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| x.contains(word))
        .collect::<&mut Vec<String>>();
}
```

I think I could just return a cloned version, but is this the only/preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible. For this to be possible, `collect` would have to return a reference to something it created, and [that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423).

You are looking for [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain):

```
fn search(word: &str, data: &mut Vec<String>) {
    data.retain(|x| x.contains(word));
}
```

If you didn't want to mutate the passed-in data, you would indeed need to return a new `Vec`:

```
fn search<'a>(word: &str, data: &'a [String]) -> Vec<&'a String> {
    data.iter().filter(|x| x.contains(word)).collect()
}
```

See also:

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)