# Lifetime of method body does not outlive lifetime of impl

Tags: rust

I tried to implement a trait for applying a function to all fields of struct trough an enum `Variant`, which should hopefully be always inlined at compilation. 
Sadly I am not able to figure out the lifetimes at all. The following code returns:

```
pub enum Variant<'a> { Str(&'a str), Int(usize) }

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Variant<'a> {
    fn from(value: &'a str) -> Self {
        Variant::Str(value)
    }
}

pub struct Foo<T> { foo: T }

pub trait Foreach {
    fn foreach(&self, fun: impl FnMut(&Variant));
}


impl<'a,T:'a> Foreach for Foo<T> where &'a T: Into<Variant<'a>>{
    fn foreach(&'a self, fun: impl FnMut(&Variant<'a>)) {
        fun("Foo: ".into());
        fun(&(&self.foo).into()); // The variant should never escape this scope. The function should consume it immediately.
    }
}
```

Following error:

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/lib.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     fn foreach(&'a self, fun: impl FnMut(&Variant<'a>)) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&Foo<T>, _)`
              found fn pointer `fn(&'a Foo<T>, _)`
note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 17:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:17:5
   |
17 | /     fn foreach(&'a self, fun: impl FnMut(&Variant<'a>)) {
18 | |         fun("Foo: ".into());
19 | |         fun(&(&self.foo).into()); // The variant should never escape this scope. The function should consume it immediately.
20 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 16:6
  --> src/lib.rs:16:6
   |
16 | impl<'a,T:'a> Foreach for Foo<T> where &'a T: Into<Variant<'a>>{
   |      ^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Variant<'_>: std::convert::From<&str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:18:13
   |
18 |         fun("Foo: ".into());
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&str>` is not implemented for `&Variant<'_>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Variant<'a> as std::convert::From<&'a str>>
   = note: `std::convert::From<&str>` is implemented for `&mut Variant<'_>`, but not for `&Variant<'_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<&Variant<'_>>` for `&str`
```

Comment: I am inclined to link to the higher-rank trait bounds doc after looking at the question for 10 seconds. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html

Comment: @idursun Thank you very much. Would you like to officially answer it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define lifetimes on a Fn trait bound returning references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566761/how-to-define-lifetimes-on-a-fn-trait-bound-returning-references)

Comment: Other questions that have to do with HRTBs: [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/3650362), [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/3650362), and [Lifetime issues with a closure argument in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51969236/3650362). It also comes up a lot when dealing with operator overloading, e.g. [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/3650362)

Comment: @FordO. posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this by using Higher-rank trait bounds which is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html)

From the document:

> `for<'a>` can be read as "for all choices of 'a", and basically produces
>   an infinite list of trait bounds that F must satisfy.

Comment: @MartenCatcher I have added an excerpt from the linked documentation.