# Moving ownership to a std::io::Chain

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I have a `Read`er that I want to prepend some bytes to, creating a `Chain`. Ideally I'd want to do this:

```rust
use std::io::{Chain, Read};

fn thingify<R: Read>(r: R) -> Chain<[u8; 3], R> {
    let mut arr = [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    // Modify arr here
    return arr.chain(r);
}
```

But that throws a compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> test.rs:7:12
  |
3 | fn thingify<R: Read>(r: R) -> Chain<[u8; 3], R>
  |                               ----------------- expected `std::io::Chain<[u8; 3], R>` because of return type
...
7 |     return arr.chain(r);
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array of 3 elements, found &[u8]
  |
  = note: expected type `std::io::Chain<[u8; 3], _>`
             found type `std::io::Chain<&[u8], _>`
```

From what I understand, this seems to be because `Read` is implemented for slices rather than arrays, and somehow my array decays to a slice here.
But when I change the array in the return type to a slice and give it an explicit lifetime like so:

```rust
use std::io::{Chain, Read};

fn thingify<'a, R: Read>(r: R) -> Chain<&'a [u8], R> {
    let arr = [1u8, 2u8, 3u8];
    // Modify arr here
    return arr.chain(r);
}
```

I just get another compiler error instead:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `arr`
  --> test.rs:19:12
   |
19 |     return arr.chain(r);
   |            ---^^^^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |            `arr` is borrowed here
```

How can I transfer ownership of my array to the `Chain` so that I can return it? Is that simply not doable with a `[u8]`?

Comment: Your first thought is correct, but at the end it will not work unless `arr` has static lifetime, if it is a constant value for your function you can use it like this([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bcfd843ccf2ca8018c74435345102b77)) otherwise it is not possible because `arr` is going to be dropped at the end of function's scope, any reference of `arr` is going to be a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Read` is implemented for [`&'_ [u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Read) but not for `[u8; 3]`, the compiler automatically converts your array into a reference slice. This mean your array must be valid as long as the slice live so as long as the `Chain` live.

There are several solutions, you could ask to the caller a mutable slice, you could make it `static` if you want to be able to mutate it, if you don't you can make it `const`, if you need to resize it you need a `Vec`, etc...

```rust
use std::io::{stdin, Chain, Read};

fn a<R: Read>(arr: &mut [u8; 3], r: R) -> Chain<&[u8], R> {
    arr.copy_from_slice(&[1, 2, 3]);
    arr.chain(r)
}

fn b<R: Read>(r: R) -> Chain<&'static [u8], R> {
    const ARR: [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
    ARR.chain(r)
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = [0; 3];
    println!("{:?}", a(&mut arr, stdin()));

    println!("{:?}", b(stdin()));
}
```

See:

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Well, I ended up creating my own struct, containing a `Box<[u8]>` and implementing `Read` manually. Thanks a bunch. :)