# How to return a reference to a method and the struct it relates to

Tags: rust

I have a function that will create one of several structs (all of which have a method of the same signature but have other, different, methods and traits); I would like to instance one of the structs in a function and return a reference to its method that can be called elsewhere.

```
// Pseudocode
type SizeGetter = fn()-> isize;

fn get_ref()-> &SizeGetter{
    let catch = Fish{weight: 12};
    &catch.get_weight()

    //Fish.get_weight() is used here but it may be any struct.method() -> isize
}

fn main() {
    let getit = get_ref();
    println!("{}", getit());
}
```

In the above my goal is to define `catch.getweight()` in a function, return a reference to that function and then call it later to get the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That original attempt could not work because you [cannot return a reference to something created in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/1233251). In this case, returning something equivalent to a method to a locally created struct value requires the value to outlive the function's lifetime as well.

We can reference a method `bar` in a struct `Foo` with `Foo::bar`, but this one isn't bound to a receiver value. There is no syntax specifically for referencing a method call on a value. The solution instead is to create a **closure that captures the value and calls the method**.

```rust
let foo = Foo::new();
move || foo.bar()
```

Considering this `Fish` struct and implementation (adjusted to comply with [naming conventions](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#c-case)):

```
struct Fish {
    weight: usize,
}

impl Fish {
    fn weight(&self) -> usize {
        self.weight
    }
}
```

A function returning *another* self-sufficient function would be written like so:

```rust
fn fish_weight() -> impl Fn() -> usize {
    let r#catch = Fish { weight: 12 };
    move || r#catch.weight()
}
```

Using:

```
let get = fish_weight();
println!("Fish weight: {}", get());
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c783ca902a7845f7a7698c28b78ae634)

Comment: how would one go about using this recursively i.e. the function returns a function that returns a function that... and so on because i can't just write infinate arrows

Comment: The method itself can be recursive. Anything else is outside the scope of this question.