# How to return tokio_postgres ToSql type from closure in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

How could I avoid repeating myself by passing the `ToSql` data as a closure, telling tokio-postgres which columns of data, from my various struct models, to `COPY`/`SELECT`/etc?

For instance, ideally I could pass various table/column args, like:

```rust
// see MRE, "copy_in" performs boilerplate to copy binary format in postgres table
copy_in(
    &mut client, // the postgres client setup in tokio
    "table_name", // meta info about what table/columns to insert
    &["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"],
    &vec![Type::INT4, Type::VARCHAR, Type::INT4, Type::INT4],
    &rows_of_struct_data, // the vec of data I plan to insert
    // then here's the hard part: which fields to extract from each row... (not works)
    |m| &[&[&m.id], &[&m.name], &[&m.range_begin, &m.range_end]] as &[&[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)]]
  );
```

`tokio_postgres` requires a type for [writing binary data during a copy](https://github.com/vincev/tsdbperf/blob/a19e428e58e9127f19a815bcc48becf06bfe2143/src/db.rs#L265), `Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)>`, and though hardcoding what gets `push`ed into that Vec works, I am puzzled how to pass an argument that decides dynamically what to `push` into it.

I have two ideas for this, but what is recommended approach?

1. As shown in this [MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf1640fbbd660b456ab3ca0c6d558a9e), I could pass a closure to my copy function that returns which columns for each row to write to stdin, but how do I type closure to avoid?:

> expected `&dyn ToSql + Sync`, found trait object `dyn ToSql`

2. Alternatively, as shown in this [MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2a8fe27fd490c811af20c9c3de2e02e), I could pass the `Vec` to my closure for it to push columns data into for each row, but that had several lifetime issues, like:

> reference to `row` escapes the async closure body here

Answer (score 1):

Out of my two approaches, I finally got #1 working, though I'm not accepting my own answer yet in case a better recommendation comes along.

Here is the working [MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=545c66e05f9ee8b0d5ee5e94db63e956)

Here is what I was missing in my understanding:

- I needed to return a single Vec for each type of column, else the `ToSql` type was violated if a single Vec contained both `i32` and `String`
- I needed to return an [owned object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683309/16400573) and **not** a reference, since functions in Rust cannot return references they own.

Interested to see for purely functional programming learning what others might recommend. This is really helpful understanding how closures can be used. #2 approach has lifetime challenges I'm interested if others have insights on.

Comment: Kudos to sharing your solution. I've built off of it into a more idiomatic form ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11d66dd20acbaedf06c44e7cb65e059e)). You can include it in your answer if you like. You did not actually need to return a `Vec` for each field, you simply needed to write it in a way that allows the compiler to deduce that it should hold trait objects and not concrete references. Your second point is true.

Comment: @kmdreko feel free to edit, that's a great improvement you deserve the credit for. Not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to return tokio_postgres &dyn ToSql + Sync type. But I resolve this problem this way below. I am inserting the data using postgres's binary copy.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
```

To populate the table, I use:

```
use tokio_postgres::types::{Type, ToSql};
use tokio_postgres::binary_copy::BinaryCopyInWriter;
use tokio_postgres::{NoTls, Error};
use futures::{pin_mut};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

    //...

    let config = format!("host={} user={} password='{}' dbname={} port={} connect_timeout=10",host, user, passwd, dbname, port);
    let (client, connection) = tokio_postgres::connect(&config, NoTls).await?;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = connection.await {
            eprintln!("Connection error: {}", e);
        }
    });

    let data: Vec<(i32,&str)> = vec![(1i32,"hello,"),
        (2i32,"world!"),
        (3i32,"how"),
        (4i32,"are"),
        (5i32,"you"),
        (6i32,"today?")];

    let sink = client
        .copy_in("COPY test (id, name) FROM STDIN BINARY")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let writer = BinaryCopyInWriter::new(sink, &[Type::INT4, Type::VARCHAR]);
    pin_mut!(writer);

    for (id, name) in data.iter() {
        writer.as_mut().write(&[&id, &name]).await.unwrap();
    }

    writer.finish().await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I use tuples to store the data, Then I unpack the tuple to insert the data on the database. The dependencies are tokio-postgres = "0.7.6", tokio = { version = "1.20.0", features = ["full"] } and futures = "0.3".