# How to instantiate a struct with new vector data

Tags: rust, lifetime

My goal is to define a struct `Wallet` that has three fields:

- A vector of `denominations` (e.g. `[1, 5, 10, 20, 100]`),
- A vector `number_of_bills` indicating the number of each denomination present in the wallet (e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1]`),
- And a vector `value` indicating the amount of money associated with each bill, i.e. the entrywise product `[0, 5, 20, 0, 100]` of `denominations` and `vectors`.

I would like to create a constructor that I can call like `Wallet::new(&denominations, &number_of_bills)` to automatically compute the `value` vector and obtain a complete instance of `Wallet`.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}


struct Wallet<'a> {
    denominations: &'a [usize],
    number_of_bills: &'a [usize],
    value: &'a [usize]
}


impl<'a> Wallet<'a> {
    fn new(denominations: &'a [usize], number_of_bills: &'a [usize]) -> Self {
        let value: Vec<usize> = denominations
            .iter()
            .zip(number_of_bills.iter())
            .map(|(&d, &n)| d * n)
            .collect();

        return Wallet {                              // (*)
            denominations: &denominations,
            number_of_bills: &number_of_bills,
            value: &value
        };
    }
}
```

This code does not compile, because in the indicated line we

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `value`
```

**How can I accomplish this task?**

Comment: Did you mean for the `Wallet` to *own* the vectors? i.e. `Vec<usize>`? `&[usize]` is an unowned slice of an array

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I am wondering if there is a way to construct this `Wallet` using borrowed arrays.

Comment: Hello, see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)

Comment: `Wallet::value` is a reference to borrowed data that lives elsewhere. The obvious question, then, is "where does the data live?" You're trying to borrow it from a local of `Wallet::new()`, but that local stops existing when the function returns. So what entity in your program is going to own it, if not the `Wallet` itself?

Comment: Thank you. I think @Caesar's link answers my question.