# Creating an instance of struct that contains a reference to some locally created struct

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a library crate with few structs that contain references to each other:

```
pub struct A ();

pub struct B<'l> (pub &'l A);

pub struct C<'l> (pub &'l B<'l>);
```

I can use them fine if I just make one instance of each struct in `fn main()`:

```
use mylib::{A, B, C}; // it is not my actually, I can't just avoid using these references in structs

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    let b = B(&a);
    let c = C(&b);
}
```

But I want to write a function that returns instances of C, given an instance of A:

```
fn init_c<'l>(a: A) -> C<'l> {
    // create an instance here...
}
```

And I have some problems with lifetimes while trying to implement this function:

```
fn init_c<'l>(a: A) -> C<'l> {
    let b = B (&a);
    C::<'l> (&b)
}
```

This is failing with errors:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `b`
  --> src\main.rs:55:5
   |
55 |     C::<'l> (&b)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^--^
   |     |        |
   |     |        `b` is borrowed here
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `a`
  --> src\main.rs:55:5
   |
54 |     let b = B (&a);
   |                -- `a` is borrowed here
55 |     C::<'l> (&b)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

So how could I implement `init_c`?

Comment: You cannot. But this really seems like a XY problem,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function/)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman XY problem? Is it something about women?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 
> Does this answer
No, it doesn't.

Comment: Why not? It says "You cannot".

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Anyway, rewriting code like in aedm's answer helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- The lifetime of `b` is tied to the function scope. No reference to `b` can be alive after the function returns. Since `C::<'l>(&b)` refers to `b`, you can't return it.
- `b` itself refers to `a`. Your argument declaration `a: A` makes the function take ownership of `a`. So the lifetime of `a` also ends with the function scope.

If you want to have a `C` object, you need a living `B` object it can refer to. And your `B` object needs a living `A` object, too.

So one possible solution is to:

1. Pass `a` by reference, and
2. add an `init_b` function to make a `B` object.

```rust
fn init_b(a: &A) -> B {
    B(&a)
}

fn init_c<'l>(b: &'l B) -> C<'l> {
    C(&b)
}

fn main() {
    let a = A();
    let b = init_b(&a);
    let c = init_c(&b);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=556095d2b09aeadf5ab4786a5466cb41)