# How can I return a custom String reference in function?

Tags: rust

I want to implement the `DeRef` trait for a custom struct, and returns an `&String`. Here's the code block

```
use std::ops;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    println! ("hello world");
}

struct MyDir {
    path: String,
}

impl ops::Deref for MyDir {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &String {
        let txt = format! ("Dir[path = {}]", self.path);
        &txt
    }
}
```

The compiler diagnostic: *cannot return reference to local variable 'txt'. returns a reference to data owned by the current function*.

I checked out some answers on stackoverflow, such as ([Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)), they all said that you cannot return a reference to a variable that is owned by a function, but then I saw a code snippet in `std::path::Path`

```
[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl ops::Deref for PathBuf {
    type Target = Path;
    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(&self.inner)
    }
}
```

Why can it return a reference held by the function here?

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can it return a reference held by the function here?

Because `Path` is [a transparent wrapper around an `OsStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#1991-1994) aka at runtime they are *the exact same thing*. So we can just get an `OsStr` from the `PathBuf` and *reinterpret* it. From a safety perspective as long as the two line up perfectly it's the same as returning a normal reference from the inner type.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the way `Path` works is the exception, not the norm. Usually, you'd see a reference type like `Path<'a>` where you own the `Path` but not the data it points to, instead of `&'a Path` where the `Path` *is* the data you don't own and you get a reference to it. In this latter case, it really looks as if a `Path` could be created out of thin air. I think it's helpful to imagine `Path` being a *type alias* to `OsStr`, which would mean that the `OsStr` that already exists is also a `Path`. This is not exactly true, but IMO it's a helpful way to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can it return a reference held by the function here?

Because it isn't returning a reference held by the function, it's returning a reference held by `self`, which the function borrows in its parameters. So ultimately the reference is held by the caller who owns `self`.

Comment: @Saber In other words, what `Path` does is as if your deref returned `&self.path` - that would compile just fine, because you're returning a reference into a part of `self`. But if you create a true local value and attempt to return a reference to that, that doesn't work (and `Path` is not doing that).