# Return struct containing borrowed value in rust

Tags: rust, reference, return, lifetime

I am trying to contruct a new `NetworkManager` from a function, but it takes a reference to another variable which is also created in the same scope.

```rust
fn test() -> NetworkManager<'_> {
    let dbus = Connection::new_system().unwrap();

    NetworkManager::new(&dbus)
}
```

How can I return this NetworkManager ?
Rn I get a compiler error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `dbus`
  --> src/lib.rs:40:5
   |
38 |     let nm = NetworkManager::new(&dbus);
   |                                  ----- `dbus` is borrowed here
39 |
40 |     nm
   |     ^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Which I understand. I just don't know how to return it properly.

NOTE: I can change the return type of the function, so I can create a new type encapsulating the dbus Connexion and NetworkManager but I didn't find a way to express this type.

Tried to create a new type:

```rust
struct Test<'a> {
    dbus: Connection,
    nm: NetworkManager<'a>,
}
```

But as there is no relation between dbus and nm here, there is no way the compiler understands what I want to do.

Comment: This is very hard to do in Rust. The easiest way will be to just give `dbus` as a parameter to the function.

Comment: If you are using [this lib](https://docs.rs/networkmanager/latest/networkmanager/struct.NetworkManager.html), it seems like only immutable access to `NetworkManager` is needed. Therefore, you *can* use for example [ouroboros](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/latest/ouroboros/), even though it might not be a good idea.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/5397009