# "Sized is not implemented for the type str" when matching against a string literal?

Tags: iterator, rust, match

I'm having trouble with some Rust code. I have a fairly simple function, but it throws errors in code that seems to be unrelated:

```
use std::env::Args;
fn without_xxx(args: Args) -> Vec<String>{
    let mut out: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut xxx = false;
    for arg in args{
        match &arg{
             "-" => xxx=true, //this line
            _ => out.push(arg.to_string())
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

If you comment out the marked line, there will be no error shown. However, with that simple line, it reveals this cryptic set of errors:

```
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str` [E0277]
<anon>: 7         for arg in args{
<anon>: 8             match &arg{
<anon>: 9                 "-" => xxx=true,
<anon>:10                 _ => out.push(arg.to_string())
<anon>:11             }
<anon>:12         }
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 note: `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 note: required by `core::option::Option::Some`
<anon>:7:13: 7:16 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str` [E0277]
<anon>:7         for arg in args{
                     ^~~
<anon>:7:13: 7:16 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:7:13: 7:16 note: `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:7:13: 7:16 note: all local variables must have a statically known size
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 error: type mismatch resolving `<std::env::Args as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == str`:
 expected struct `collections::string::String`,
    found str [E0271]
<anon>: 7         for arg in args{
<anon>: 8             match &arg{
<anon>: 9                 "-" => xxx=true,
<anon>:10                 _ => out.push(arg.to_string())
<anon>:11             }
<anon>:12         }
<anon>:7:9: 12:10 help: see the detailed explanation for E0271
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you've read other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/155423) about the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28175528/155423), so I'll just cover this specific case.

You want to use `&arg[..]` instead of `&arg`:

```
fn without_xxx(args: Args) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut out = vec![];
    let mut xxx = false;

    for arg in args {
        match &arg[..] {
             "-" => xxx = true,
            _ => out.push(arg)
        }
    }

    out
}
```

I'll admit that the error is a strange one. Here's what I think is happening:

When you do `&arg`, you are taking a reference to a `String`. `String`s implement [`Deref<Target = str>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), which means they can participate in *deref coercions*.

The match arm is of type `&str`. When comparing the two types, the compiler sees you have a `&String` and are trying to match it to a `&str`. It automatically dereferences both values and applies deref coercions. However, a `str` cannot be a standalone type, thus you get the error.

Using `&arg[..]` triggers the [`Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait instead. This produces a `&str`, and thus the match arm doesn't do any automatic dereferencing or coercion.

Additionally:

1. There's no need for an explicit type on `output`
2. Use implicit returns at the end of functions / closures.
3. There's no need to call `to_string` because `arg` is already a `String`.

---

For fun, here's a version that uses `filter_map`, `collect`, and just a plain `if`:

```
fn without_xxx(args: Args) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut xxx = false;

    let out = args.filter_map(|a| {
        if a == "-" {
            xxx = true;
            None
        } else {
            Some(a)
        }
    }).collect();

    // I assume you do something with `xxx` here

    out
}
```

This *may* have a performance benefit as it can *potentially* allocate an upper-bound for the size of the vector.

Another version:

```
fn without_xxx(args: Args) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut xxx = false;

    let out = args.filter(|a| {
        let matched = a == "-";
        xxx = xxx || matched;
        !matched
    }).collect();

    // I assume you do something with `xxx` here

    out
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn't it preferred to use `&*x` over `&x[..]` nowadays?

Comment: @Veedrac good point! I'm not sure *which* is more idiomatic. I think I picked up `&x[..]` in The Days Before 1.0, and haven't thought too much about it since. Both should compile to the same code, so it's a matter of what looks more obvious, I guess.