# Why is `let ref a: Trait = Struct` forbidden?

Tags: rust

We have a noncopyable type and a trait:

```
struct Struct;
trait Trait {}
impl Trait for Struct {}
```

If we create a `&Struct` and dereference it, we get an rvalue reference that we can use to initialize a by-ref binding:

```
let a: &Struct = &Struct;
let ref a: Struct = *a;
```

We can also directly initialize that by ref binding:

```
let ref a: Struct = Struct;
```

But if we declare our variable binding to require a reference, only the first code snippet works

```
let a: &Trait = &Struct;
let ref a: Trait = *a;
```

Attempting to do this directly

```
let ref a: Trait = Struct;
```

Or by going through loops

```
let a: &Struct = &Struct;
let ref a: Trait = *a;
```

Or

```
let ref a: Trait = *&Struct;
```

Will give us a `mismatched types` error. Obviously they aren't the same type, but inference works for references.

Is this simply not implemented (yet?) or is there a deeper reason it's disallowed?

Answer (score 5):

There's a little bit of unsized subtlety going on here. The key difference between

```
let a: &Struct = &Struct;
let ref a: Struct = *a;
```

and

```
let a: &Trait = &Struct;
let ref a: Trait = *a;
```

Is that the expression `*a` produces a value whose size is not known at compile-time. This manifests as an error when we attempt to do:

```
let ref a: Trait = Struct as Trait;

<anon>:6:24: 6:39 error: cast to unsized type: `Struct` as `Trait`
<anon>:6     let ref a: Trait = Struct as Trait;
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:6:24: 6:30 help: consider using a box or reference as appropriate
<anon>:6     let ref a: Trait = Struct as Trait;
```

In general, the compiler can't know the size of a bare trait used as a type, like `Trait` is used here. This is because *any type* can implement `Trait` - so the size of trait can be *any size*, depending on the type that implements it. So, that explains why `let ref a: Trait = Struct` and `let a: &Struct = &Struct; let ref a: Trait = *a` don't work, because casting a `Struct` to a `Trait` is an unsized cast.

As for why your working trait code snippet works, looking at the MIR for these two examples, we can see that the compiler is treating the two above assignments slightly differently:

```
let a: &Struct = &Struct;
let ref a: Struct = *a;

bb0: {
    tmp1 = Struct;
    tmp0 = &tmp1;
    var0 = &(*tmp0);
    var1 = &(*var0);
    return = ();
    goto -> bb1;
}

let a: &Trait = &Struct;
let ref a: Trait = *a;

bb0: {
    tmp2 = Struct;
    tmp1 = &tmp2;
    tmp0 = &(*tmp1);
    var0 = tmp0 as &'static Trait + 'static (Unsize);
    var1 = &(*var0);
    return = ();
    goto -> bb1;
}
```

We see that the compiler has to do a cast to a *trait object* `&'static Trait + 'static` to satisfy the implicit coercion of `&Struct` to `&Trait`. From there, the ref pattern is simply `var1 = &(*var0);`, which in this case is a simple assignment from the trait object `var0` to the trait object `var1`.

This is similar to the MIR generated by this function:

```
fn stuff() {
    let sized = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    let slice : &[u8] = &sized;
    let ref other_slice = *slice;
}

bb0: {
    var0 = [const 1u8, ..., const 0u8];
    tmp2 = &var0;
    tmp1 = &(*tmp2);
    var1 = tmp1 as &'static [u8] (Unsize);
    var2 = &(*var1);
    return = ();
    goto -> bb1;
}
```

Since the type `[u8]` is unsized, it does a similar cast to a *slice*, which is quite similar in layout to a trait object. Ultimately, the compiler allows the code that doesn't introduce any unsized locals.

Comment: How do you get the MIR output??

Comment: so basically it means rustc can't unsize rvalue references, but only actual references. @PiotrZolnierek: there's a `MIR` button on http://play.rust-lang.org