# Why must items on the stack have a size that's known at compile time?

Tags: rust

I get why they must have *constant size*, but I don't get why that size must be *known at compile time*. Even C allows variable length arrays on the stack. What does this limitation help Rust with?

Comment: See also [Why can fixed-size arrays be on the stack, but str cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673145/155423); [Why is `let ref a: Trait = Struct` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36057645/155423); [What does “Sized is not implemented” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/155423)

Comment: *Even C allows* — C allows lots of bad things. The fact that a language allows something doesn't make it _good_.

Comment: @Shepmaster: the question has to do with what is the technical reason for that choice, not about how useful VLAs seem

Comment: Sure, but there has to be at least one good use for a feature, otherwise the technical reason could be "there's no good reason to support this". I'm not making a statement that VLAs are or are not useful, just that saying "C can do *X*" is a weak argument.

Comment: @Shepmaster: it's only argues that it is *possible* to have sizes known at runtime

Comment: "the question has to do with what is the technical reason for that choice, not about how useful VLAs seem" that VLA are terrible is a good technical reason for not having VLA in other languages.

Comment: @Masklinn: turns out it's being added to the language, so, that *was not* the reason, for rust developer team at least.

Comment: C11 remove this feature for a reason :p

Comment: Seems to me a good reason is in a no-alloc (e.g. some no-std) environment where dynamic memory allocation isn't available, yet you want to be able to create a temporary buffer with the size known only at run time.  Trivial to toss one on the stack in C, possibly infeasible in Rust (if this still hasn't been stabilized in 2022, that is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even C allows variable length arrays on the stack.

C can relatively easily support this because of its trivial semantics.

When you have to call destructors/`drop`, this is far less trivial, so Rust didn't initially support it because it's effort to implement and doesn't give all that much of a benefit.

Eventually, Rust will support this (and [already does on nightly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html)) thanks to [RFC 1909 — unsized rvalues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1909-unsized-rvalues.md).

Comment: *already does* — pedantically, not quite: ["VLAs are not implemented yet"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html#variable-length-arrays)

Comment: *this is far less trivial*  — I'd be interested to learn why the addition of destructors makes this harder; it's not an obvious leap for me.

Comment: Just as an example, a VLA of `Drop` types needs to store the object count so that it can correctly iterate on drop.

Comment: Wouldn’t it have to always store the object count to disallow out-of-bounds indexing (and thus memory unsafety) regardless of if the elements implement `Drop`?

Comment: Hm, true. Frankly, I don't know the concrete pitfalls. I just remember from the time I worked on Clang that the other devs complained about having to support VLAs in C++.