# Are Dynamically Sized Typed always on the heap?

Tags: rust

My learning of Rust has got me to learn about Dynamically Sized Types (DST) and I understand these are types whose size cannot be known at compile time. E.g. `str`.

My question now is, will I be right to say that DST can never exist on the stack, and they only exit on the heap?

Also, will it be correct to say sized types on the other hand can exist on the stack:

`(eg. let x:u32 = 10)`

but can also be made to exist on the heap, for example via the use of Box

`(eg let x: Box<u32> = Box::new(10))`

Are these statements above correct?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673303/12299000), types like `[T]` and `str` can't be stored on the stack because they are unsized. (It's not a duplicate question, but the answer seems to be there.) [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65112979/12299000) is also related.

Comment: `str` can be placed in `'static` storage, however, which is not heap-allocated but loaded directly from the program data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsized types are often best interpreted as "just the data". Wherever that data lives is not important to the definition of DSTs.

For example, you can have a dst living on the stack:

```rs
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let y = &x[..];
```

The array `x` lives on the stack and its data is understood as a dst when you put it under a reference while in `y`.

`y` has the type `&[i32]` -- that is, a reference to some `i32`s. In this case, the reference points to data on the stack.

Other notable places you can place DSTs are:

- The heap through allocations (`Box`, `Rc`, `Arc`, `Vec`, etc.)
- The read-only portion of your program (usually through string constants such as `"abc"`).
- Unknown places (through `extern type`s in nightly code).

In essence, any type can exist on the stack and heap (barring lifetime related issues). If you have a sized type on the stack, box it up and you have it on the heap. If you want a slice on the stack, slice into an array or string. If you want a trait object, take a reference to a value on the stack, etc. etc.

Comment: the more i learn the more i realise that perhaps the trying to form a hard distinction between stack/heap is not that important

Comment: @FinlayWeber It really isn't. There are other locations than those as well - for example, the program segment (where `static` variables live) and memory-mapped regions.