# Why can fixed-size arrays be on the stack, but str cannot?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer

Answers to [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) describe how `&str` and `String` relate to each other.

What is surprising is that a `str` is more limited than a fixed-sized array, because it cannot be declared as a local variable. Compiling

```rust
let arr_owned = [0u8; 32];
let arr_slice = &arr_owned;

let str_slice = "apple";
let str_owned = *str_slice;
```

in Rust 1.32.0, I get

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
```

which is confusing, because the size of `"apple"` can be known by the compiler, it is just not part of the `str` type.

Is there a linguistic reason for the asymmetry between `Vec<T>` <-> `[T; N]` and `String` <-> `str` owned types? Could an `str[N]` type, which would be a shortand to a `[u8; N]` that only contains provably valid UTF-8 encoded strings, replace `str` without breaking lots of existing code?

Comment: `str` is actually more comparable to an *unsized slice* `[T]`, rather than a fixed size array `[T; N]`. And you can't have a variable of type `[u8]` either.

Comment: And what would be the point of such feature ?

Comment: You can use [smallstr](https://docs.rs/smallstr/0.1.0/smallstr/struct.SmallString.html) or something like that if you want to optimize the string allocations.

Comment: I got great insights from these comments and answers. We had 2 type aliases: `type A = String;` and `type B = Vec<u8>` in our code. And a method taking `&A` triggered clippy. That was when I started looking for these parallels between `&str` and `&[u8]` and this slight asymmetry in the type-system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> asymmetry between `Vec<T>` <-> `[T; N]` and `String` <-> `str`

That's because you confused something here. The relationships are rather like this:

- `Vec<T>` ⇔ `[T]`
- `String` ⇔ `str`

In all those four types, the length information is stored at runtime, not compile time. Fixed size arrays `([T; N]`) are different in that regard: they store the length at compile time, but not runtime!

And indeed, both `[T]` and `str` can't be stored on the stack, because they are both unsized.

> Could an `str[N]` type, which would be a shorthand to a `[u8; N]` that only contains provably valid UTF-8 encoded strings, replace `str` without breaking lots of existing code?

It wouldn't replace `str`, but it could be an interesting addition indeed! But there are probably reasons why it doesn't exist yet, e.g. because [the length of a Unicode string is usually not really relevant](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/). In particular, it usually doesn't make sense to "take a Unicode string with exactly three bytes".

Comment: The link to the Unicode string processing is quite useful. Living in a locale which writes names and dates in strange orders, has non-ascii characters, I thought I saw most problems with localization. Boy, I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> `[T]` and `str` can't be stored on the stack, because they are both unsized

While this is true today, it may not be true in the future. [RFC 1909 introduces *unsized rvalues*](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1909-unsized-rvalues.html). One of the powers that this feature would give is [*variable-length arrays*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html#variable-length-arrays):

> The RFC also describes an extension to the array literal syntax: `[e; dyn n]`. In the syntax, `n` isn't necessarily a constant expression. The array is **dynamically allocated on the stack**

No mention is made of whether a string will be directly possible, but one could always create a stack-allocated array of bytes to be used as storage for a string.

Comment: I remember pcwalton being strongly opposed to the use of VLAs.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I can certainly see them being misused or overused, but the same feature gives us `Box<FnOnce()>` so I'm cautiously optimistic!